# Trying to automatically populate our manual test plans into every build/iteration in TFS?

Tags: testing, tfs, azure-devops, test-plan

Is it possible to automatically clone and populate a new test plan (that is the same as the current one) for each new iteration and build in TFS? Our Test Plans are built, but we don't know how to have a new one to properly track what testing did or did not get done with each build and iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You could use TFS REST API to [create test plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/test/test%20%20plans/create?view=vsts-rest-5.0) by specifying the "name", "area", and "iteration":

```
POST https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/test/plans?api-version=5.0-preview.2

{
  "name": "ANewPlan",
  "area": {
    "name": "Fabrikam-Fiber-TFVC\\Quality assurance"
  },
  "iteration": "Fabrikam-Fiber-TFVC\\Release 1"
}
```